# Proving Bernoulli Inequality using already proved result.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, inequality

This is an exercise from *A Course in Calculus and Real Analysis* by Sudhir R. Ghorpade and Balmohan V. Limaye:

[image]

I prove the first assertion of (i) as follows:

> If $m=1$, then the result is trivial. Now, assume for $m \geq n$, $a_1 \leq ...\leq a_m$ and $A_n \leq A_m$. This gives $$A_{m+1}-A_n~\geq~A_{m+1}-A_m=\frac{a_1+...+a_m+a_{m+1}}{m+1}-\frac{a_1+...+a_m}{m}=\frac{(a_{m+1}-a_1)+(a_{m+1}-a_2)+...+(a_{m+1}-a_m)}{m(m+1)}\geq0.$$So that, $A_{m+1}\geq A_n$. Similarly, the result where $a_1\geq ... \geq a_m$ can be proved.

For the second assertion, I don't know how to prove the converse, I can only prove one part.:

> If $a_1=...=a_m$, then, clearly, $A_n=A_m$.

(ii) can be proved using identity $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+...+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$ and some casework. No problems here.

For (iii), I think we can let $r=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q \in \Bbb N$ and $p,q$ are relatively prime. This gives us $$(1+a)^{\frac{p}{q}} \geq 1+\frac{pa}{q}$$ I don't see how I can use (ii) to prove the desired result.

**In short, Here are my questions:**

1. Is my proof of the first assertion of (i) correct?
2. How do I prove the second assertion of (i), that is, the condition for equality?
3. How do prove (iii) using (ii)?

I would like some hints first. If I still can't figure it out, I'll ask for a full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What concerns do you have with your proof?

> Your proof is correct.

2. When can equality hold in the following inequality?

$\frac{(a_{m+1}-a_1)+(a_{m+1}-a_2)+...+(a_{m+1}-a_m)}{m(m+1)}\geq0$

> Since each term is non-negative, equality holds when all of the terms on the LHS = 0.
>  Hence $a_{m+1} = a_1$, $a_{m+1} = a_2, \ldots $

3. Use (ii). Play around with various possibilities and try them out.

**Hint:** How can we make $x^m = (1+a)^r$?

> Let $ r = \frac{p}{q}$.
>  Let $x = (1+a)^\frac{1}{q} \geq 0$. Let $m = p, n = q.$
>  Then $ \frac{ ( 1+a)^r - 1 } { p }  \geq \frac{(1+a)^1 - 1 } { q} \Rightarrow (1+a)^r \geq 1 + ra  $.

$ r >  1 \Rightarrow m > n $, so equality holds when $ x = 1 \Rightarrow a = 0$.

---

Note: (ii) can be proven using (i) directly.

> Set $a_i = x^{i} - x^{i-1}$. Then $A_i = \frac{x^i - 1 } { i}$.

Comment: @DS2830 Edited.

Comment: @DS2830 Alright, I've added how to prove (iii). I encourage you to just keep playing with the setup.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!